# python, subprocess: launch new process when one (in a group) has terminated

Tags: python, subprocess

I have *n* files to analyze separately and independently of each other with the same Python script `analysis.py`. In a wrapper script, `wrapper.py`, I loop over those files and call `analysis.py` as a separate process with `subprocess.Popen`:

```
for a_file in all_files:
    command = "python analysis.py %s" % a_file
    analysis_process = subprocess.Popen(
                                            shlex.split(command),
                                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                                            stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    analysis_process.wait()
```

Now, I would like to use all the *k* CPU cores of my machine in order to speed up the whole analysis. 
Is there a way to always have `k-1` running processes as long as there are files to analyze?

Comment: [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) ;)

Comment: Is `analysis.py` the same script?

Comment: yes! it's as simple as in the example above. 
I'll give a look at multiprocessing.Pool, thanks :)

Comment: In the past I just did it in bash by grepping `ps ax` and counting the process instances, but I thought there might be a neater way. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This outlines how to use [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) which exists exactly for these tasks:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool, cpu_count

# ...
all_files = ["file%d" % i for i in range(5)]


def process_file(file_name):
    # process file
    return "finished file %s" % file_name

pool = Pool(cpu_count())

# this is a blocking call - when it's done, all files have been processed
results = pool.map(process_file, all_files)

# no more tasks can go in the pool
pool.close()

# wait for all workers to complete their task (though we used a blocking call...)
pool.join()


# ['finished file file0', 'finished file file1',  ... , 'finished file file4']
print results
```

Adding Joel's comment mentioning a common pitfall:

> Make sure that the function you pass to pool.map() contains only objects that are defined at the module level. Python multiprocessing uses pickle to pass objects between processes, and pickle has issues with things like functions defined in a nested scope.

[The docs for what can be pickled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Comment: That's pretty neat! Thank you. So basically, in order to adapt it to my case, I just put the call to `subprocess.Popen` in the above function `process_file`, and it's done. Right?

Comment: @RickyRobinson Nope, the processes are opened implicitly in the pool. You don't need to open processes yourself. You need to process the file and that's it :)

Comment: I'm only mentioning this because it seems to be a common pitful, but make sure that the function you pass to `pool.map()` contains only objects that are defined at the *module level*. Python multiprocessing uses `pickle` to pass objects between processes, and pickle has issues with things like functions defined in a nested scope. See the docs here for [what can be pickled](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle.html#what-can-be-pickled-and-unpickled)

Comment: It **is** a common pitfall. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. In my case, in `process_file`, I would simply pack the necessary parameters (among which the file name used in this question), and call the analysis function of another Python module.  Would this be bad?

Comment: This is fine. You're doing everything in the process itself (opening the file, writing to it, closing it...), and all you're passing is a file name as an argument via the map call.