# Start multiple processes in python without waiting

Tags: python

I have trouble starting multiple processes simultanousely without waiting for termination.

I am iterating through directory and then process content of file in external script.

Command line execution looks like following:

```
 python process.py < /dir/file
```

Here is some sample of python code

```
for root, directory, file in os.walk(dir):
    for name in file:
        input_file = open(os.path.join(root, name))
        input_text = input_file.read().encode('utf-8')
        input_file.close()

        command = "python process.py"
        process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), shell=False, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        process.stdin.write(input_text)
        log.debug("Process started with pid {0}".format(process.pid))
        process.communicate()
```

Is there any way to start them without waiting for termination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Store them in a list and don't use [`process.communicate()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) in the loop. It blocks.

From the docs:

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate**. The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

So result should be something like:

```
# list to store processes after creating them
prcoesses = list()

for root, directory, file in os.walk(dir):
    for name in file:
        input_file = open(os.path.join(root, name))
        input_text = input_file.read().encode('utf-8')
        input_file.close()

        command = "python process.py"
        process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(),
                                   shell=False,
                                   stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        processes.append(process)

        process.stdin.write(input_text)
        log.debug("Process started with pid {0}".format(process.pid))
        # process.communicate()

 # wait for processes to complete
 for process in processes:
     stdoutdata, stderrdata = process.communicate()
     # ... do something with data returned from process
```

To have limited number of processes you may want to use a [process pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) which is available through the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Comment: Your solution worked if i put all processess on the list, but is there any way to control number of running processes? I mean If i have like 50 files to process but I want only 10 at a time ?

Comment: Thank you, after some fight I found solution how to run processes from Pool. Still didnt manage how to do lazy iteration on Pool.

Comment: This is probably not how you want to use pool. see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27567046/python-subprocess-launch-new-process-when-one-in-a-group-has-terminated/27567546#27567546

You can try and read more answers on questinos that use the multiprocessing tag, these are mine: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:948550+[multiprocessing]